# Store: Changing Order Statuses from SAEF?

Tags: expresso-store, expresso, saef

Is there a way to change the status of Expresso Store orders via a SAEF?

For people working in the picking/packing department of a webshop, I would like to create a simple page with a few buttons: "Start picking" "Packed" "Shipped" or "Delayed due to ..." so they can easily use a simple touch screen device and quickly update the status of an order.

Anyone ever tried this? Don't know if it is even possible.

Answer (score 3):

It's not possible using Store's built in tags. You could do this by writing your own plugin though, if you're comfortable getting your hands dirty with a bit of PHP.

To programatically change an order status in Store 2, you can find an order by ID like so:

```
$order = Store\Model\Order::find($entry_id);
```

You can then find and change the status like this:

```
$status = Store\Model\Status::where('name', $status_name)->first();
$order->updateStatus($status, $current_member_id, $custom_message);
```

Answer (score 1):

Received a mail back from the developers.

It isn't possible at this moment but they are willing to put it on their list of potential things to do. No commitment towards if/when.

Answer (score -1):

Um, yep the [EE Docs](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/channel_form/#status) even give you an example. You could turn that into radio group or some such to achieve the function you seek.

Comment: But the orders aren't available in the normal entries, so the normal entries/docs don't apply, I assumed.

Comment: Soz, didn't see the store bit.