# Create an extension to update the status

Tags: expresso-store

I'm just starting to work with Store 2.x and wondering if it's possible for me to create an extension that updates the order status once the order is complete. I know I'm needing to use the 'store_order_complete_end' hook, but not sure how I can update the status at this point. Can somebody point me in the right direction? I'm basically wanting to update the status to one of 2 things depending on what products they are buying.

Thanks,
Dan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Derek was very close. I actually wrote a [similar answer to this the other day](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/a/18648/150).

You need to find the actual status before you update the order. Since you already have the $order object, all you need to do is this:

```
$status = Store\Model\Status::where('name', $status_name)->first();
$order->updateStatus($status);
```

FYI in case you are wondering, you can loop through the order items like this:

```
foreach ($order->items as $item) {
    echo($item->entry_id); // etc
}
```

Comment: Great - I'm sure that will work fine - I'll check next week and let you know if I have any problems, but I can't see why I would. Thank you!

Comment: It's cool that you can still call the built in functions from store. Really makes the site so much more dynamic!

Answer (score 3):

If you do a `print_r($order)` inside of your extension, you'll see what you have access to inside of the `$order` object/array.

You can then loop through the order items it contains and check for your products, then update the `exp_store_orders` table with a new status for that order (I'm sure its `_order_id` is contained in the `$order` object as well).

Comment: Thanks - I was really wondering if there was a way to call the already updateStatus that already exists and give it a new status. Ideally I want it to send the email and update the status history as well, not just updating the actual status. Sorry for not being clear on that one!

Comment: Shot in the dark here, but try this in your extension: `ee()->store->order->updateStatus('status_name');`.

Comment: Unfortunately not... I get the following error:
Fatal error: Class 'Store\Service\OrderService' not found in *********/expressionengine/third_party/store/src/Store/Container.php on line 32

Comment: I'll ping Adrian on this.